# The attempt to bind "/%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" in the workspace failed as this URI is malformed when running on Netlify

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, web, manifest

Having this error on my website when it goes live but the error is not shown in local:host just for the live build. I cannot seem to find a solution. Help would be great! [the error that is shown when inspecting the website][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jap8g.png

```
  "short_name": "TestWeb",
  "name": "TestWeb",
  "description": "Best Place On Earth",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "type": "image/x-icon",
      "sizes": "256x256"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what type of app that you're building, but for the sake of assumption, let's say you're using a "create-react-app" app or something else cli-generated.

This seems to happen when you try running "netlify deploy" before anything else. What you can do is create a netlify.toml file (read more here: [link](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/file-based-configuration)) and provide the basic criteria, assuming you've got a create-react-app app:

```
[build]
  publish = "build/"


  command = "npm run build"
```

Once you've done that, try running `netlify build`. Try now running the bundled app locally using serve, or something similar. If that works, then run `netlify deploy` and see whether it worked live.

I ran into this problem just now, and this is how I solved it.

Comment: thanks for the help! It worked for me! +1